# Good reference book for the theory and chords of MINOR keys

Tags: chord-progressions

While decoding Take Five by Paul Desmond and Dave Brubeck I've been told that it's in the key of D Minor - but my books only seem to cover the Major Keys and the Major Scales - is there a good reference book that delves into the details of MINOR KEYs? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that the minor key is the same as a major key 3 half-steps above? i.e. the key of Dm is the same as the key of F?

Comment: What books are you currently reading? I can't think of any that treat the major and minor keys separately, since they are highly interrelated, and few songs in the real world are exclusively major or minor.

Comment: @meganoob - that bit of information is only true to a certain extent. In fact, it's quite a misleading statement with no extra information.

Comment: I've yet to find sheet music showing Take Five in Dm! It's available in a variety of keys, Dm not being one of them! The original track seems like it's in Ebm, which sounds a little odd, but bear in mind the solo is played on alto sax, which is an Eb transposing instrument, so for Paul Desmond, his chart would have been written in key Cm. The piano part would still have to be shown in key Ebm. Recommendations for books, etc., are out of bounds on this site.

Comment: @meganoob d minor has a C#

Comment: I'm confused then, does the key of Am not contain any sharps or flats, the same as C? or the key of Dm contain one flat, the same as F?

Comment: I just want to add as well, if you haven't already, the wikipedia page for Take Five has a rough and ready analysis of the recording of Take Five https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Five#Structure

Comment: @meganoob it depends what you mean by a key "containing sharps or flats". Minor key tonality is generally understood to encompass a range of notes beyond the diatonic, so to say that the *key* of A minor doesn't contain any sharps or flats might be misleading, even though it's true that the key *signature* of A minor doesn't have any sharps or flats.

Comment: As Tim says, It's in Eb minor, and it was originally published in Eb minor. But by the time the music appeared in the library I had already learnt it from the record and was playing it Em 'cos my parents' piano was flat. Most sax players are reluctant to switch to C#m! You **may** be luckier persuading them to play it in B minor.

Comment: I’m curious about these books (plural, not just one!) you talk about that only contain information on major keys and scales, that is hard to believe.

Comment: Okay, I see the issue, I was talking strictly key signatures. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Forget this book: chances are this book is either rather basic or filled with errors.

Study tonal harmony by famous textbooks, college level or not: Aldwell & Schachter, Schoenberg, Kostka & Payne, Piston, Huron et cetera.

For something more complex after this, search for neo riemannian theory.

Comment: I understand the relationship between Major and Relative Minor - I was looking for semething that focuses on Minor keys so the TEXT BOOKS sound like a good idea! THANKS!

Comment: I like Kostka & Payne’s *Tonal Harmony* and Aldwell & Schachter’s *Harmony and Voice Leading* a lot. There’s no wrong way with them.